# Output file from python function using tweepy won't stop printing

Tags: python, function, twitter, while-loop, tweepy

I am trying to use this function I found to gather tweets from a specified user, populate a list with the text portion of the json object that the tweet is comprised of, make some modifications to the string, and then print to a text file. Here is my code:

```
import tweepy
import re

# Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""


def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    # Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method

    #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    # initialize a list to hold all the tweets
    alltweets = []

    # make initial request for most recent tweets
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name, count = 200, include_rts = False)

    # save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    # save the id of the oldest tweet minus one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    # keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print ("getting tweets before %s" % (oldest))

        # all subsequent requests use the max_id parameter to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name, count = 200, max_id = oldest)

        # save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        # update the ID of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print ("...%s tweets downloaded so far"  % (len(alltweets)))






    # transform the tweets into a 2D array that will populate the 
    outtweets = []
    for tweet in alltweets :
        outtweets.append(tweet.text.encode("utf-8"))
#    outtweets = [[tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]

    print(outtweets[:1])

    outtweets = [w for tweet_text in outtweets for w in tweet_text.split()] # Split each individual word into a string
    outtweets = [w for w in outtweets if w] # Print only words to the list / Gets rid of blank strings
    outtweets = [w.lower() for w in outtweets] # Cast all words to lowercase




    output_file_name = screen_name + "_tweets.txt"
    delimiter = "\n"

    with open(output_file_name, 'w') as f:
        for tweet in outtweets :
            f.write(delimiter.join([str(item) for item in outtweets]))








if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pass in the username of the account you want to download
    get_all_tweets("BarstoolBigCat")
```

My problem is that my output file won't stop printing. I think it has something to do with my `while` loop, but I am unfamiliar with them and not quite sure what to change. In a perfect world, my function stops after gathering 1000 tweets and printing their contents to a text file.